# Upgrade to Smartface App Studio 4.4.0 -> Text-Button

Tags: smartface.io

After Upgrading to Smartface 4.4.0 the text of textbuttons ist converted to Uppercase on Android (Could not test it for iOS.) Also the animation "flipFromLeft" for pages seems not to work anymore? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Uppercase problem is a known case, and will be fixed. This problem occurs only for Lollipop devices.

For the second question, can you please share the script(only the line in which animation is done will be enough).

Comment: var animation2 = { motionEase : SMF.UI.MotionEase.accelerating, transitionEffect : SMF.UI.TransitionEffect.flipFromLeft, transitionEffectType : SMF.UI.TransitionEffectType.push, fade : false, reset : false }; Pages.Pg_Pass.show(animation2);

Comment: With 440, flip animation(flipFromLeft and flipFromRight) is removed for Android, but it is still valid for iOS. You can use different animations while showing page, such as leftToRight, downToUp.